# Firebase push notifications not working properly in some devices

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

For push notification am using FCM. Iam facing some problem in VIVO V3 phones. **Same code works in other devices (Blackberry,Huawei,Samsung) with all below scenarios**
I have tested with 3 Scenarios;

1. When app is in foreground.
2. When app is in background.
3. When app is in completely kills.

The first 2 condition is working well.Only the problem with 3rd one.When app kills am not getting any notification.

The below code using at server side to send Data Notification message,

```
 {
   "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
   "data" : {
     "title" : "Notification Title",
     "body" : "Notification Message",
   },
 }
```

The following code am using in my app,

```
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import me.leolin.shortcutbadger.ShortcutBadger;


public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "debug";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
        // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
        //
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        if (remoteMessage.getData()!=null)
            Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message get data: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null)
            Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());

            //            Map<String, String> map = remoteMessage.getData();
            Log.d(TAG , "Json DATA Notification::" + jsonObject.toString());

            //message will contain the Push Message
            String message = jsonObject.getString("title");

            String messageContent = jsonObject.getString("body");

            sendNotification(message, messageContent);


        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("debug" , "Exception");
        }
    }


    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     */

    private void sendNotification(String messageTitle, String messageBody) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

}
```

I have tested with Blackberry,Huawei,Samsung devices.Its working perfectly.Kindly help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some apps dont allow background notification.You need to enable auto start manager for these devices.

Comment: @ShivamOberoi i dont have such option in my phone.And when i go inside my app info show notification already enabled.

Comment: Let me answer...

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this in onCreate().You need to enable auto start manager as some devices doesn't allow.

```
private void enableAutoStart() {
    if (Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("xiaomi")) {
     private void enableAutoStart() {
    if (Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("xiaomi")) {
      new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).title("Enable AutoStart")
        .content(
          "Please allow AppName to always run in the background,else our services can't be accessed.")
        .theme(Theme.LIGHT)
        .positiveText("ALLOW")
        .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter",
              "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);
          }
        })
        .show();
    } else if (Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("Letv")) {
      new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).title("Enable AutoStart")
        .content(
          "Please allow AppName to always run in the background,else our services can't be accessed.")
        .theme(Theme.LIGHT)
        .positiveText("ALLOW")
        .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe",
              "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);
          }
        })
        .show();
    } else if (Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("Honor")) {
      new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).title("Enable AutoStart")
        .content(
          "Please allow AppName to always run in the background,else our services can't be accessed.")
        .theme(Theme.LIGHT)
        .positiveText("ALLOW")
        .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager",
              "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);
          }
        })
        .show();
    } else if (Build.MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase("oppo")) {
      new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).title("Enable AutoStart")
        .content(
          "Please allow AppName to always run in the background,else our services can't be accessed.")
        .theme(Theme.LIGHT)
        .positiveText("ALLOW")
        .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
            try {
              Intent intent = new Intent();
              intent.setClassName("com.coloros.safecenter",
                "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity");
              startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
              try {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClassName("com.oppo.safe",
                  "com.oppo.safe.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity");
                startActivity(intent);
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                try {
                  Intent intent = new Intent();
                  intent.setClassName("com.coloros.safecenter",
                    "com.coloros.safecenter.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity");
                  startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception exx) {

                }
              }
            }
          }
        })
        .show();
    } else if (Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("vivo")) {
      new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).title("Enable AutoStart")
        .content(
          "Please allow AppName to always run in the background.Our app runs in background else our services can't be accesed.")
        .theme(Theme.LIGHT)
        .positiveText("ALLOW")
        .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
            try {
              Intent intent = new Intent();
              intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.iqoo.secure",
                "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.AddWhiteListActivity"));
              startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
              try {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager",
                  "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
                startActivity(intent);
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                try {
                  Intent intent = new Intent();
                  intent.setClassName("com.iqoo.secure",
                    "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.BgStartUpManager");
                  startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception exx) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
            }
          }
        })
        .show();
    }
  } new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).title("Enable AutoStart")
        .content(
          "Please allow AppName to always run in the background,else our services can't be accessed.")
        .theme(Theme.LIGHT)
        .positiveText("ALLOW")
        .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter",
              "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);
          }
        })
        .show();
    } else if (Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("Letv")) {
      new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).title("Enable AutoStart")
        .content(
          "Please allow AppName to always run in the background,else our services can't be accessed.")
        .theme(Theme.LIGHT)
        .positiveText("ALLOW")
        .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe",
              "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);
          }
        })
        .show();
    } else if (Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("Honor")) {
      new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).title("Enable AutoStart")
        .content(
          "Please allow AppName to always run in the background,else our services can't be accessed.")
        .theme(Theme.LIGHT)
        .positiveText("ALLOW")
        .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager",
              "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);
          }
        })
        .show();
    } else if (Build.MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase("oppo")) {
      new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).title("Enable AutoStart")
        .content(
          "Please allow AppName to always run in the background,else our services can't be accessed.")
        .theme(Theme.LIGHT)
        .positiveText("ALLOW")
        .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
            try {
              Intent intent = new Intent();
              intent.setClassName("com.coloros.safecenter",
                "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity");
              startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
              try {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClassName("com.oppo.safe",
                  "com.oppo.safe.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity");
                startActivity(intent);
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                try {
                  Intent intent = new Intent();
                  intent.setClassName("com.coloros.safecenter",
                    "com.coloros.safecenter.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity");
                  startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception exx) {

                }
              }
            }
          }
        })
        .show();
    } else if (Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("vivo")) {
      new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).title("Enable AutoStart")
        .content(
          "Please allow AppName to always run in the background.Our app runs in background else our services can't be accesed.")
        .theme(Theme.LIGHT)
        .positiveText("ALLOW")
        .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
            try {
              Intent intent = new Intent();
              intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.iqoo.secure",
                "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.AddWhiteListActivity"));
              startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
              try {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager",
                  "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
                startActivity(intent);
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                try {
                  Intent intent = new Intent();
                  intent.setClassName("com.iqoo.secure",
                    "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.BgStartUpManager");
                  startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception exx) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
            }
          }
        })
        .show();
    }
  }
```

Comment: In MainActivity onCreate() or MyFirebaseMessagingService?

Comment: ApplicationClass have you made it?

Comment: No.Is that i can add it in to my MainActivity Class?

Comment: MaterialDialog.Builder are using some lib?

Comment: Yes let me add that.Compile this  compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162894/discussion-between-shivam-oberoi-and-sunisha-sindhu).

Comment: how to check if autostart enabled or not ?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue seems a critical one. You will need to check out few things to get resolve the issue :

> - First make sure you are getting the same issue on all different devices or on any specific device
> - Because when we did found the similar issue it was occurred only on specific devices
> - Now you have to give auto start permission to the application & enable for the device on which you are getting the issue

**Edit :**

Try to use notification payload instead of data payload as per Firebase docs :

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Notification Title",
      "body":"Notification message"
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: For the first one i have clearly mentioned Blackberry,samsung and Huwaei its working

Comment: 2nd one VIVO ph i have tested in that it has the problem

Comment: http://support.dailyhunt.in/support/solutions/articles/4000093200-are-you-using-vivo-devices-not-getting-notifications-even-after-enabling-show-notification-

Comment: Nop there is some problem....auto start is already enabled in my app,but iManager its not enabled

Comment: Thank you...Let me find solution and will update you

Comment: Using notification would change the behaviour

Answer (score 2):

**This May Helps You**

**Recently i face this problem i solve this issue by autostart**

Ref : https://docs.telerik.com/platform/knowledge-base/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-cannot-receive-push-notifications-on-android-when-the-app-is-closed

[Push notification not working when application is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443075/push-notification-not-working-when-application-is-closed/52444024#52444024)

Not For Only Firebase

some Android devices cannot receive push notifications when the app is closed. The app can receive push notifications when it is running, either in the foreground or in the background.

**Cause**

> On these devices most of the apps are not permitted by default to be
>   awaken in the background. This way the app cannot process the received
>   push notification when it is not running.

Currently, this behavior is identified only on devices from the following manufacturers:

- Huawei
- Xiaomi
- Asus

**Solution**

> You need to modify certain settings on your device.

```
Huawei devices
```

> Open Settings → Protected Apps

Place your application in the list

```
Xiaomi devices
```

> On the app screen tap on the Security app Select Permissions →
>   Autostart Locate your app in the list and enable "Autostart" Restart
>   the device

```
Asus devices
```

> Locate the Auto-start Manager as noted here Locate your app in the
>   list and enable "Allow"

**Edit 2**

Get More Info From Here

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/41

Answer (score 1):

this is a [library](https://github.com/judemanutd/AutoStarter) to do what you want.

```
dependencies {
    // ... other dependencies
    implementation 'com.github.judemanutd:autostarter:1.0.3'
}
```

then you can use the following to bring the autostart permission manager of your app.

```
AutoStartPermissionHelper.getInstance().getAutoStartPermission(context);
```

currently t support :

- Xiaomi
- Redmi
- Letv
- Honor [ Untested ]
- Oppo [ Untested ]
- Vivo [ Untested ]
- Huawei
- Samsung
- Asus
- One Plus [ Untested ]