# Push notification not working when application is closed

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am working in react native project where I required to have push notification from server to be implemented in my app. I tried to use firebase as the notification provider. For that, I used react-native-firebase package. I tried this example [link](https://medium.com/@yangnana11/how-to-set-up-firebase-notification-in-react-native-app-android-only-4920eb875eae) Its working fine when the app is running. But notification failed to come when the app is closed. 
So how can I achieve this

My target Android version is KitKat

Comment: You need a background service in addition to the default class App to handle 
 the incoming notfications.

Answer (score 6):

**Recently i face this problem i solve this issue by autostart**

Ref : https://docs.telerik.com/platform/knowledge-base/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-cannot-receive-push-notifications-on-android-when-the-app-is-closed

Not For Only Firebase

some Android devices cannot receive push notifications when the app is closed. The app can receive push notifications when it is running, either in the foreground or in the background.

**Cause**

> On these devices most of the apps are not permitted by default to be
>   awaken in the background. This way the app cannot process the received
>   push notification when it is not running.

Currently, this behavior is identified only on devices from the following manufacturers:

- Huawei
- Xiaomi
- Asus

**Solution**

> You need to modify certain settings on your device.

```
Huawei devices
```

> Open Settings → Protected Apps

Place your application in the list

```
Xiaomi devices
```

> On the app screen tap on the Security app Select Permissions →
>   Autostart Locate your app in the list and enable "Autostart" Restart
>   the device

```
Asus devices
```

> Locate the Auto-start Manager as noted here Locate your app in the
>   list and enable "Allow"

**Edit 2**

Get More Info From Here

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/41

Comment: I am using nexus through the android simulator, Push notification is working only when the app is running.

Comment: @AnujK.C. enable auto start in setting

Comment: Push notification is working, But how can I set image with this notification

Comment: @AnujK.C. 3rd Edit

Comment: oh sorry for that wait

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki I am not receiving notification from fcm when my app is not running in background but other installed app are receiving notification even if I haven't enable any settings for those apps. I am using xiaomi device

Comment: @Kanchan make sure you have registered your token to your server and sending notification on that devices, or if you sending notification on topic then make sure your divice subscribed that topic.

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki I am using postman to push notification and I have put the fcm token of device in request body, I am not using any topic

Comment: @Kanchan share the url that you are using

Comment: @Kanchan on this api request are you sending any data in title , body fields ?. If yes then check you android code

Comment: @kanchan if you still not work then share more details on email or whatsapp, contact details mentioned on profile

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Anuj there are two types of notification in firebase,  notification and data payload .
If you send as Notification it will work only when app is in foreground , ask backend team to send notification as data payload you have to set notification payload as null
[Check Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)